# HBase for storing the output data of Hadoop-Hive clusters OR the storage of RAW data?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hbase, hive

I have query companies using hive-hadoop clusters are using the HBase as the storage of RAW data or the storage of Output Data to further integrate with R?

Also, what are the pros and cons of storing the RAW data in S3 as compared to HBASE?